# How to make a dictionary from the pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Suppose I have a dataframe with 2 columns:

```
col1  fre    
a,d    2
b,d    4
a,h    1
k,l    5
b,c    3
a,f    7
```

Can I make a dictionary in which the `key` is the first element of `col1`. and the `value` is each pair of the second element of `col1` and `fre`.?

For example :

```
{'key': 'a',
  ['Results': {'d': 2}, {'h': 1},{'f': 7 } ]} , {`key`: 'b', ['Results' : {'d' : 4},{'c' :3} ]}, {`key`: 'k', ['Results' : {'l' : 5} ]}
```

Comment: The expected output is not valid python.

Comment: @Ch3steR anything similar to it is ok

Comment: So you need a list of dicts, right?

Comment: @VinayG yes anything that I can have access to these information

Comment: @elham If one of the answers has helped you solve the problem, please consider accepting it via clicking the checkmark. Please note that there is obviously no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new column first using apply function, then use that column to group and format data

```
df['gkey'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col1'].split(',')[0], axis=1)
l = []
for key, value in df.groupby('gkey'):
    l.append({'key': key, 'Results': [{row['col1'].split(',')[1]: row['fre']}for index, row in value.iterrows()]})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use numpy, you can create an outer dictionary first with all the col1 first values as keys. The set operation takes care of multiple occurrences of those values.
Then you can iterate over all keys in your dict and generate new ones.

```
mydict = {okey: {} for okey in set([col1[0] for col1 in df['col1'].tolist()])}
for okey in mydict.keys():
    msk = np.where([m.startswith(okey) for m in df['col1'].tolist()])[0]
    mydict[okey] = {row[0][-1]: row[1] for row in np.array(df)[msk]}
```

Comment: According to the tags and the question description, OP rather wants to use pandas. Still a good alternative in my opinion! :-)

Comment: I agree, your solution is more elegant. But I guess you need to somehow split the first column first, for it to work on the specified data frame format.

Comment: Completely agree with you, though due to *"suppose I have a dataframe with 2 columns"* I thought he has already implemented a working dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! Pandas has the `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` method - for the documentation click [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

You got your dataframe with two columns and just call `df.to_dict()` on it, just like in the code example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2],
                   'col2': [0.5, 0.75]},
                  index=['row1', 'row2'])

df.to_dict()
```

The `df` variable now holds a dictionary with the syntax: `{'col1': {'row1': 1, 'row2': 2}, 'col2': {'row1': 0.5, 'row2': 0.75}}`. In case you have problems with initiating a DataFrame, please check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) on `pandas.DataFrame`.